# Laravel blade non numeric id is returning 0

Tags: php, laravel

I have a livewire component which renders a currency selector dropdown. This is an eloquent object where the id is the standard 3 letter iso currency unit i.e. `USD` or `GBP` this table also has a symbol field which will give `$` and `£` in a dropdown. However when i call `$currency->id` in my blade file it is being rendered as 0 and not the 3 letter string I expect.

This is my livewire files:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Currency;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;

class EditExternalItem extends ModalComponent
{
    public collection $currencies;
    public string $currency_unit = 'GBP';

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->currencies      = Currency::whereIn('id', ['GBP', 'EUR', 'USD'])->get();
        $this->currency_unit   = $jpi->currency_unit;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.currency-item');
    }
}
```

and the blade file:

```
<x-modal formAction="update">
    <x-slot name="title">
        Edit a Purchase Item / Subscription
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content">
        <select
            name="currency_unit"
            wire:model="currency_unit"
            class="p-2 px-4 py-2 pr-8 leading-tight bg-white dark:bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow appearance-none hover:border-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
            >
            <option value="-1">Please Select a Currency Unit...</option>
            @foreach ( $currencies as $currency)
                <option value="{{ $currency->id }}">{{ $currency->symbol }} {{ $currency->id }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="buttons">
        <x-jet-button class="mx-2" type="submit">
            {{ __('Submit') }}
        </x-jet-button>
        <x-jet-button type="button" class="mx-2" wire:click="$emit('closeModal')">
            {{ __('Close') }}
        </x-jet-button>
    </x-slot>
</x-modal>
```

and this is the rendered html which has 0 instead of the correct id

```
        <select name="currency_unit" wire:model="currency_unit" class="p-2 px-4 py-2 pr-8 leading-tight bg-white dark:bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow appearance-none hover:border-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
            <option value="-1">Please Select a Currency Unit...</option>
            <option value="0">€ 0</option>
            <option value="0">£ 0</option>
            <option value="0">$ 0</option>
        </select>
```

Any ideas why? A few things occur to me but can't really see if this would be the case.

The id is a string (which is unique), should this be named something else (I read about id being a livewire keyword).

Also I have used ModelComponent but would expect this to generate the same result in a normal livewire component (this just shows it in a modal box).

Is it because I have a collection (again why would it not work as it does with other models right?)

Finally using xdebug and a breakpoint where the content is rendered shows that the currencies are populated and have the iso strings set as id so it is correct at this point.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__set_state(array(
   'items' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    App\Models\Currency::__set_state(array(
       'connection' => 'mysql',
       'table' => 'currencies',
       'primaryKey' => 'id',
       'keyType' => 'int',
       'incrementing' => true,
       'with' => 
      array (
      ),
       'withCount' => 
      array (
      ),
       'preventsLazyLoading' => false,
       'perPage' => 15,
       'exists' => true,
       'wasRecentlyCreated' => false,
       'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
       'attributes' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'EUR',
        'symbol' => '€',
        'rate' => 1.1964856822541,
      ),
       'original' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'EUR',
        'symbol' => '€',
        'rate' => 1.1964856822541,
      ),
       'changes' => 
      array (
      ),
       'casts' => 
      array (
      ),
       'classCastCache' => 
      array (
      ),
       'attributeCastCache' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dates' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dateFormat' => NULL,
       'appends' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dispatchesEvents' => 
      array (
      ),
       'observables' => 
      array (
      ),
       'relations' => 
      array (
      ),
       'touches' => 
      array (
      ),
       'timestamps' => true,
       'hidden' => 
      array (
      ),
       'visible' => 
      array (
      ),
       'fillable' => 
      array (
      ),
       'guarded' => 
      array (
        0 => '*',
      ),
    )),
    1 => 
    App\Models\Currency::__set_state(array(
       'connection' => 'mysql',
       'table' => 'currencies',
       'primaryKey' => 'id',
       'keyType' => 'int',
       'incrementing' => true,
       'with' => 
      array (
      ),
       'withCount' => 
      array (
      ),
       'preventsLazyLoading' => false,
       'perPage' => 15,
       'exists' => true,
       'wasRecentlyCreated' => false,
       'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
       'attributes' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'GBP',
        'symbol' => '£',
        'rate' => 1.0,
      ),
       'original' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'GBP',
        'symbol' => '£',
        'rate' => 1.0,
      ),
       'changes' => 
      array (
      ),
       'casts' => 
      array (
      ),
       'classCastCache' => 
      array (
      ),
       'attributeCastCache' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dates' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dateFormat' => NULL,
       'appends' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dispatchesEvents' => 
      array (
      ),
       'observables' => 
      array (
      ),
       'relations' => 
      array (
      ),
       'touches' => 
      array (
      ),
       'timestamps' => true,
       'hidden' => 
      array (
      ),
       'visible' => 
      array (
      ),
       'fillable' => 
      array (
      ),
       'guarded' => 
      array (
        0 => '*',
      ),
    )),
    2 => 
    App\Models\Currency::__set_state(array(
       'connection' => 'mysql',
       'table' => 'currencies',
       'primaryKey' => 'id',
       'keyType' => 'int',
       'incrementing' => true,
       'with' => 
      array (
      ),
       'withCount' => 
      array (
      ),
       'preventsLazyLoading' => false,
       'perPage' => 15,
       'exists' => true,
       'wasRecentlyCreated' => false,
       'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
       'attributes' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'USD',
        'symbol' => '$',
        'rate' => 1.3542339440595,
      ),
       'original' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'USD',
        'symbol' => '$',
        'rate' => 1.3542339440595,
      ),
       'changes' => 
      array (
      ),
       'casts' => 
      array (
      ),
       'classCastCache' => 
      array (
      ),
       'attributeCastCache' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dates' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dateFormat' => NULL,
       'appends' => 
      array (
      ),
       'dispatchesEvents' => 
      array (
      ),
       'observables' => 
      array (
      ),
       'relations' => 
      array (
      ),
       'touches' => 
      array (
      ),
       'timestamps' => true,
       'hidden' => 
      array (
      ),
       'visible' => 
      array (
      ),
       'fillable' => 
      array (
      ),
       'guarded' => 
      array (
        0 => '*',
      ),
    )),
  ),
   'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
))
```

I'm using php8.1 and laravel9.19.0 with livewire2.10.6 and version 1.0.7 of wire-elements/modal (all latest versions)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem too, turns out that Laravel assumed every eloquent model `id` column is incremented and it will try to cast it to integer. So just put:

`public $incrementing = false;` in your model and that should fix the issue.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your livewire component's variables that are required in view inside render like this:

```
return view('livewire.currency-item',['currencies' => $currencies]);
```